# Combinatorial Game. Who wins if both players play optimally

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

> Players *A* and *B* play a game optimally and move alternately. They
>   start with 1. Each player in his turn multiplies the current number
>   with any integer from [2,9]. If after a player's turn, the number is
>   more than or equal to **n**, he wins.
>
> A starts. Given **n**, who wins?

For example,

Numbers 2,3..,9 are winning numbers (Player A will win)

Numbers 10,11,..,18 are losing numbers (Player A will lose)

Numbers 19,20,..,162 are winning numbers

What would be the winning strategy? How can the Sprague-Grundy theorem be applied to solve this?

Comment: Sounds very homework'ish to me.

Comment: It was actually a programming competition question. The question originally was that you can only multiply 2 OR 9 to the number. I'm trying to solve a modified version of the question

Comment: @Rushil I tried to answer your question, but I did not show it s special case of theorem you mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Sprague-Grundy theorem](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=algorithmGames) each state of an impartial game can be assigned a non-negative integer called *Grundy number*, such that the player who moves in this state will lose iff this number is 0, and win iff this number is non-zero.

If the Grundy numbers for the states are known, then the winning strategy is to always make a move to a state in which Grundy number is 0.

The algorithm for computing Grundy number for some state of a general game is as follows:

```
if current player can't make a valid move:
    Grundy number := 0 (this player has lost)
else:
    for each move in this state:
        for each sub-game the game splits into after that move:
            compute Grundy number of the sub-game
        compute XOR of Grundy numbers of the sub-games
    Grundy number := MEX of those XORs
```

`MEX` is minimum excludant function. `MEX` of a set of non-negative integers is equal to the smallest non-negative integer, that does not belong to this set.

For example:

```
MEX(0) = 1
MEX(0, 1) = 2
MEX(0, 2) = 1
MEX(0, 1, 2) = 3
MEX(0, 1, 3) = 2
MEX(1, 2, 3) = 0
MEX(10, 100, 1000) = 0
```

Naive implementation of this algorithm for this game in Python 3 may look like this:

```
import functools
from itertools import count

def mex(s):
    for i in count():
        if i not in s:
            return i

@functools.lru_cache(10000)
def sprague_grundy(n, cur=1):
    if cur >= n:
        return 0
    move_results = {sprague_grundy(n, cur*move) for move in range(2, 9+1)}
    return mex(move_results)

for i in count(1):
    print(sprague_grundy(i))
```

Often the easiest way to understand the general formula for the Grundy number is to just look at the sequence and try to notice the relationships.
In this game you can figure out the general formula by simply looking at **n** numbers for games in which player A wins in inital state, without actually calculating Grundy numbers.

But we can still look at the counts of Grundy numbers of the initial state of the game for consecutive **n** (0 means player A loses in the initial state, 1,2,3,4 mean player A wins):

```
$ python3 sprague_grundy.py | uniq -c
     1 0
     1 1
     2 2
     4 3
     1 4
     9 0
    18 1
    36 2
    72 3
    18 4
   162 0
   324 1
   648 2
  1296 3
   324 4
  2916 0
```

It is possible to notice that for player A all the losing initial states are for

[image: n \in \left( 9\cdot18^k .. 18^{k+1} \right ]: \textup{for} : k=0,1,2,...]

Or in other words the initial state for player A is losing iff

[image: \left\lfloor{\log_{18}{\frac{n-1}{9}}}\right\rfloor > \left\lfloor{\log_{18}{\frac{n}{18}}}\right\rfloor]

Comment: Excellent answer. This is what I was looking for. A logarithmic time solution. Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: I was wondering how you came up with that inequality..can you explain that?

Comment: @Rushil No special derivation, just tried to describe the ranges of zeros with a single mathematical formula. According to a list of numbers and formula above, zeros (n which have losing initial state for A) are from 10 to 18, from 163 to 324, from 2917 to 5832 and so on. log_18 and dividing by 9 and 18 follow naturally from factorising those numbers. Floor operation, greater sign and n-1 part are small modifications to make it work together in all cases. In simple games it is usually easy to notice some obvious periodic pattern in Grundy numbers, but there are exceptions (e.g. Grundy's Game)

Comment: Yea I just realized that for every range of integers which contain losing starting values, the first number is of the form 2^i * 9^(i+1) + 1. So it's not difficult to generalize it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you make an array **A[]** where **A[i]** stores whether number **i** is a winning position or losing with respect to the player who starts the game.Let it be player **A**. Basic rule, from a losing position you can go only to a winning one and a winning position is such that there is always a losing position reachable from it.Following code is explanatory ( **1** means winning w.r.t to **A** and **0** means losing).

```
       for each i from 1 to 9
           A[i]=1
       for each i from 10 to n
           flag=0
           A[i]=0
           for each j from 2 to 9
               if i is divisible j and A[i/j] is 0
                  flag=1
           if flag is 1
               A[i]=1
```

Now if **A[n]** is **1** it is winning for him else he loses.
This is an **O(n)** solution both in time and memory.You can reduce memory, but
time I can't come up with a better solution. There might be a **O(1)** solution but I am unaware of it.

Comment: Thanks.
The constraints on n are high ( <= 10^9 ) so this might not be feasible in terms of memory, nevertheless it's a good start :-)

Comment: @Rushil in terms of time it would take 10^10 iterations which is about 10-20 sec and memory you can reduce for example if you want to calculate A[i] you dont need answers for numbers less than [i/9] so at max memory will be an array of int of size 10^8 which is possible to create.But yeah still this solution is more appropriate for small n